# Add "n" fields when click on "Add another item"

Tags: 7, entities

When I click on "Add another item", It should create 10 new fields.
Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: where you want to create Add another item in node or webform??

Comment: I have article content type,  and I have an image field here. To this image field, I want to add this functionality....node

Answer (score 0):

There is an open feature request for this on Drupal.org but it is not currently supported out of the box. See https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/1394184 for details